# switching getElementById to ClassName for creating popup does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm probably going to get spanked for asking this but all the posts on this site are too technical for my meager knowledge of js.  I found code to create a popup of an image that I like, but since it uses getElementById it only works for the first image.  I tried switching to getElementsByClassName and made the global changes in the css and html using . not # etc., but this doesn't permit the additional images to pop up.  I did consult other posts on this site such as "How to switch a getElementById to getElementsByClassName" which was not clarifying for me since the answer advises to make a switch to code using getElementsByClassName even though the post's title references switching from getElementById.  Other posts were opaque as to how to update or edit the js to get what I need.  I appreciate any guidance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/qkv6kzb.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Barton's website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>

.myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.gallery {
    width: auto;  
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: ;
    border: 2px black solid;
}
.photo {
    border: 20px red solid;
    padding: 20px;
    }
.photo img {
    padding: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="gallery">
        <table class="photo" width= height=>
        <tr>
            <td><img id="myImg" class="photobox" src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_262-109.jpg" alt="262-109, 67th Ave., Queens Boulevard Line" width="256" height="171" />

            <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div></td>

            <td><img id="myImg" class="photobox" src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_262-197.jpg" alt="262-197, 67th Ave., Queens Boulevard Line" width="256" height="171" />

            <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div></td> 

            <td><img id="myImg" class="photobox" src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_287-153.jpg" alt="287-153, Flushing Ave., IND Crosstown Line" width="256" height="171" />

            <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>

  <script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use jQuery instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code also will solve your problem,

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var imageArray =  document.getElementsByClassName("photobox");

for(var i=0;i<imageArray.length;i++){
    var img = imageArray[i];
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```

You don't need to have multiple modal html codes, only one following content is enough,

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only JavaScript:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("photobox");
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
var clickFn = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
};
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = clickFn;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("img.photobox").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").show();
    $("#img01").attr( src, this.src );
    $("#caption").html(this.alt);
});
$("span.close").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked as well as the other reply.  I wish you could give credit for different correct answers on this site.